# Can I simply "repoint" apache to use a different version of PHP?

Tags: php, apache2

I have 2 versions of php installed in different directories. I can use both from the command line. However, I'm not able to figure out how to get apache to use a different one (in other words, it uses one, but I'd like to try running with the other).

Can I change simlinks or something? What process would I use to "repoint" apache to use my other installation of php?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have php7.2 and 7.4 installed. 
When you invoke phpinfo(), php 7.2 is responding (and displayed) and you want 7.4 running. 
Hereafter how to proceed:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
systemctl restart apache2
```

Working for me on Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

In your apache httpd.conf file there is a explicit include for the php module.  Whatever this points to is the version of php to be used.

Look for a line something like this:

```
 LoadModule php5_module  libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Then change it to point to the library of the new version of php.

If this isn't in your httpd.conf file it may be in another conf file found in /etc/httpd/conf.d/

Any changes to these files require a reload or restart of apache.